# Reputation bubble animation in graph is too fast

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-graph

The text of the reputation bubble on the [Reputation graph tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) moves at a different speed to the bubble itself:

[image]

The text is slower so appears below / above the box as it moves.

Comment: never mind, found it

Comment: Well ,t always end up OK so don't think it's really a bug. Just don't move so fast. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's not my mouse going fast, it's just me moving between the bars.

Comment: I see. Well, still quite minor but worth fixing.